# Executors and Trend are empty in Allure report with pipeline multibranch

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, allure

I have a pipeline multibranch with a Jenkinsfile. In this file i have :

```
stage('Rapport Allure') {
        script {
                allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
                ])
        }
    }
```

But in Allure report Executors and Trend widget are empty.
Executors : *There is no information about tests executors*
Trend : *There is nothing to show*

Same problem with a simple pipeline.
But it's works in a free-style project Jenkins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found,i change the path like this :

```
stage('Rapport Allure') {
        script {
                allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: 'allure-results']]
                ])
        }
    }
```